# Encryption and Decryption Project not Ending Using Loops

Tags: python, encryption

I have been working on a fun little project of working on encrypting some message and then possibly decrypting them. The only thing is that it gets to when I call the instance of my class, but then it never comes back and continues to run. Are there any tips to fixing this, thank you!

```
import datetime

beta_value = {"A":5, "B":9, "C":11, "D":12, "E":13, "F":14, "G":8, "H":6, "I":7, "J":15, "K":16, "L":4, "M":17, "N":18, "O":19, "P":20, "Q":10, "R":21, "S":22, "T":23, "U":24, "V":3, "W":25, "X":26, "Y":27, "Z":28, "": 0, ".": 1, "!": 2}

#Find the day
d = datetime.datetime.now()
day = d.strftime("%d")

#The beta value is the value for each letter in the alphabet that is the number of nodes it takes to construct the capital counter part of that letter, and +n if needed

#Create the encryption and decryption class
class Beta():
    def __init__(self, sen):
        self.liste = []
        self.listd = []

        #Leaf through the letter for encryption or decryption
        for let in sen:
                self.liste.append(self.encrypt(let))
                self.listd.append(self.decrypt(let))

        # resulte = 
        # resultd = 

    #Create encryption
    def encrypt(self, let):
        allowed = True
        beta_uf = int((int(beta_value[let.capitalize()]) + int(day)) % 28)

        #Check if the beta value exists in the beta_value list
        while allowed:
            for key, value in beta_value.items():
                if int(beta_uf) == value:
                    beta_f = key
                    allowed = False
        if allowed:
            beta_uf += 1

        return beta_f

    #Create decryption
    def decrypt(self, let):
        pass

#Input words
words = input("What is your text? ")

#Create instance of the class
B = Beta(words)

#Encrypt or decrypt?
e_or_d = input("Encrypt or Decrypt? ")

if e_or_d == "encrypt" or "Encrypt":
    print(B.liste)
else:
    print(B.listd)
```

Also, please don't criticize me about how bad this is...

Follow up: Hi, the comments below helped get rid of my main issue(also I updated my code from above to the new stuff), but now I want to try and include spaces, but it seems to have an issue with those giving:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 49, in <module>
    B = Beta(words)
  File "main.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.liste.append(self.encrypt(let))
  File "main.py", line 28, in encrypt
    beta_uf = int((int(beta_value[let.capitalize()]) + int(day)) % 28)
KeyError: ' '
```

Lol, nvm, I fixed it.... :P

Comment: You're stuck in an infinite while-loop. neither of the break-statements are reached. Also, as an addendum, I think you wanted to use `def encrypt(self, let)` and `def decrypt(self, let):` in your method-definitions. The most probable reason for the infinite-loop, is that the for-loop is never executed, because `beta_value.items()` returns an empty iterator.

Comment: Thx, but when I do that, then it says I am missing another operator...

Comment: My comment before is slightly incorrect. You're still inside of an infinite while-loop, and the break-statements are being executed. However, the only thing they are doing, is breaking the for-loop, not the while-loop. Which means that the next time around the while-loop, the for loop is entered again, and is hitting the same break-statement, exiting _only_ the for-loop.

Comment: You also have to change the calls to `Beta.encrypt(let)` into `self.encrypt(let)`

Comment: Thx, I just got rid of the breaks since it was okay if I didn't include them(it was just for runtime), and that fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things in your code that could be their own question, however this is about why your code "is stuck" and not returning any values.

The reason for that is because your while-loop doesn't hit an exit-condition, and is stuck in an infinite loop.

What your while-loop is basically doing is this:

```
while True:
    for i in range(10):
        break
```

The `break` that is issued inside of the for-loop will only "break-out" from the for-loop, and not touch the status of the while-loop.

There are multiple ways to solve this. One way to solve this, is to involve further flow-control and using the for-loops (often forgotten) else-statement.

An else-statement following a for-loop will only execute if the whole for-loop was executed to its completion.

Let's see it in action with this piece of code:

```
>>> for i in range(3):
...     print(i)
... else:
...     print("The for-loop was executed to its end.")
... 
0
1
2
The for-loop was executed to its end.
```

If we use this behavior with a `continue` statement, then we could make a while-loop "miss" its own `break` statement.

Here is a (not so simple) example:

```
import random
while True:
    for i in range(3):
        rint = random.randint(0,10)
        print(f'range {i=} {rint=}')
        if i == rint:
            print("Breaking the for-loop.")
            break
    else: # Only runs when the whole for-loop was executed.
        print("Continuing to the next for-loop!")
        continue
    print("Breaking the while-loop.")
    break
```

Output of one run:

```
range i=0 rint=6
range i=1 rint=0
range i=2 rint=0
Continuing to the next for-loop!
range i=0 rint=0
Breaking the for-loop.
Breaking the while-loop.
```